# Constraint on a metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Given a metric of the form $$ds^2=dr^2+a^2\tanh^2(r/b)d\theta^2$$
why does it follow that $a=b$?
I can't quite spot a constraint condition...

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54627/2451

Comment: There are *no* constraints on a metric apart from ones your particular problem would impose on it. So we need more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe so you'd recover $$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$$ at small $r$. I think that we need more details about this metric (what are its motivations/applications)

Comment: That's right, the condition $a=b$ follows from the smoothness at $r\to 0$. For $a\neq b$, there would be a deficit or excess angle - the geometry would be a cone with a sharp singular tip at $r=0$.